# Is there a way to disable back or forward navigation in Webview2 winforms

Tags: c#, webview2

In webview2, setting source property to Uri for navigating.

Let's say First URL is opened in webview2 then navigated to another URL.
With the back button on Right-click context menu, able to navigate to the first page.

From google search, found there is no direct way to disable back and forward as of now.

In the normal system forms browser, performed an approach like below which is working

added a bool variable(like IsMyNavigationCall), setting it to true whenever just before navigating to some URL
Added a check in NavigationStarted event and if it's false(when navigation triggered from actions like back) cancelling the request and resetting the bool variable.

In Webview2, it's not working. The problem is navigation is not cancelled even after setting CoreWebView2NavigationStartingEventArgs.cancel to true.

Is there any way or kind of hack to prevent navigation between the back and forward?

Comment: I think you should do this in javascript, here you can call `History.replace` when navigating, then there will be only one page in the history, which of course makes it impossible to got back/forward,

Comment: [History Inteface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/replaceState) doesn't have Replace member. It has ReplaceState. Should that be used?

Comment: Sorry for the typo, that was what I meant.

Comment: On second thought: May be `Location.replace` is better: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace

Comment: back button is disabled after changing code from `webView.CoreWebView2.Navigate("https://www.google.com");` to `await webView.ExecuteScriptAsync("window.location.replace('https://www.google.com')");`

Comment: You can also assign an eventhandler to all links, that calls `event.preventDefalt()` and then use `window.location.replace` to navigate to the link. Then it shouldn't add to history.

Comment: I find your post a bit confusing.  If you don't want the user to be able to navigate forward/back, then why provide buttons for the user to do so?

Comment: @user9938 It is the browser default button present in the context menu.

Comment: `window.location.replace` is not working for the local file path (eg: file:///C:/1.html)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're looking for [CoreWebView2.HistoryChanged Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.historychanged?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1108.44). In order to enable/disable a "Back" button and a "Forward" button when a new URL is navigated to in WebView2, try the following:

**Given**:

- **WebView2 control**: webView21
- **Back button**: btnBack
- **Forward button**: btnForward

```
//subscribe to CoreWebView2 events (add event handlers)
webView21.CoreWebView2.HistoryChanged += CoreWebView2_HistoryChanged;

                           ...

private void CoreWebView2_HistoryChanged(object sender, object e)
{
    btnBack.Enabled = webView21.CoreWebView2.CanGoBack;
    btnForward.Enabled = webView21.CoreWebView2.CanGoForward;
}
```

Comment: I was looking to prevent back /forward navigation in webview2 or prevent the saving of history. 

CanGoBack and CanGoForward are property with only Get exposed

Comment: This is not answer on the question

Comment: @23W: This post is more than a year old, but thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the context menu and the accelatorkeys via CoreWeView2.Settings
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/reference/winrt/microsoft_web_webview2_core/corewebview2settings?view=webview2-winrt-1.0.1245.22#arebrowseracceleratorkeysenabled

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/reference/winrt/microsoft_web_webview2_core/corewebview2settings?view=webview2-winrt-1.0.1245.22#aredefaultcontextmenusenabled

Example:

```
webView.CoreWebView2.Settings.AreDefaultContextMenusEnabled = false;
webView.CoreWebView2.Settings.AreBrowserAcceleratorKeysEnabled = false;
```

Comment: This Disables all keyboard shortcuts and context menu

Comment: It also does not (despite what the msdn reference says) disable the mouse4 and mouse5 hotkeys to navigate back and forth.